# Do you know this function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I'm looking for a real-valued function with the following properties:

- $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1$
- $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) = -\infty$
- $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and $0<f(x)\leq 1$ always

$1-\sqrt{x}$ fits the first two criteria and may just need the right factor. I would also appreciate ideas on how to approach problems like this generally. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = c +\sqrt{|x|}$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ otherwise.

Comment: doesn't have to have a single definition.  Have $f(x) = g(x)$ for $x$ near $0$  where $g(x)$ does the first 2) and have $f(x) = h(x)$ for $x$ large where $h(x)$ does the last 1).

Comment: $c-\sqrt x=\frac{c^2-x}{c+\sqrt x}$, so I think it fit the third too.

Comment: I suggest that you modify the title as it suggests that there is only one such function, which is clearly not the case. By the way there is no such function differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @sirous.  $\lim_{x\to \infty} c-\sqrt x=-\infty$ and $c-\sqrt{x} < 0$ when $x > c^2$ so it must certainly doesn't satisfy the third.

Comment: This is not possible, the second and third conditions are incompatible. By the way, $1-\sqrt x$ does not fulfill the second.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I forgot a minus sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the simplest solutions are $\frac{1}{x^\alpha+1}$ and $(1+x)^\alpha-x^\alpha$ with $\alpha \in (0,1)$
- every function of the form $f(x) = 1 - \sqrt{1-g(x)}$ with $g(0) = 1$ and  $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$ works, some examples are $g(x)=e^{-x}$ or $\frac{1}{x+1}$.
- some trig solutions are: $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{arccsc}(x+1)$ and $\exp(x^\alpha)$

Answer (score 3):

Any $$f(x) = \frac{c + \sqrt{\vert x \vert}}{1+ a x^{2p}} \text{ or } \left(c + \sqrt{\vert x \vert}\right) e^{-a x^2}$$ with $a >0$ and $p \ge 1$ integer will do the job.

**Approach:**

- Find a function satisfying the first two criteria.
- Multiply it by a function that converges at $\infty$ fast enough to zero, that is positive and has a zero derivative at zero.
- *Side element: notice that such a function will never be differentiable at zero.*